# How can I automatically populate a newly added column that references a foreign key?

Tags: psql

I'm working through the PSQL guide online and came across this problem.

I have two tables, one that looks like this called `properties`:

[image: properties table]

and the other that looks like this called `types`:

[image: types table]

I would like to add a NEW column to the first bigger table. The column would be called type_id and would be a foreign key referencing the type_id in the smaller table. Is there way to automatically populate this new column since that type_id would be given based on the type value in the same `properties` table?

The best idea I've come up with is to just manually populate it or just create some bash script. Is there a simpler PSQL querying method that would do the trick?

Comment: After creating the type id column (not as foreign key yet), you could set it depending on the type field, I guess? `update properties set type_id = 1 where type = 'nonmetal';`. Repeat for the others. Then make the new column a foreign key?

Comment: Mmm, I see. That seems to be the best way so far. Thanks!